# grub2 on xubuntu trusty does not display boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

The boot menu does not show up even though /etc/default/grub contains:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Yes, I did update-grub. Holding the shift key did not help either.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `sudo grub-mkconfig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy fix for your problem is to install grub customizer. Not only can you easily customize grub with it, you can customize burg too which is what I'm using. You can mess with the settings until you fix it. It's pretty straight foward. (Type or copy these onto the terminal then press enter after each line.)

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: This works fine, thanks! Still, I don't understand why, in 14.04,  the boot menu is not visible by default. And how I could have repaired that without this graphical interface.

Comment: Trying to find out, I found that grub-customizer can restore the old situation with the Revert button. However: it does _not_ restore /boot/grub/grub.cfg if you _only_ change (under General settings->visibility->Show menu) the visibility of the menu.

Comment: When you press the save button, it should run an (sudo) update-grub similar command after making your changes. That should reload grub.cfg